# Add prefix to field in Phoenix model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a phoenix model:

```
schema "news" do
  field :title_ru,              :string
  field :title_en,              :string
  field :title_uk,              :string
end
```

I want automate this. Example, i have a list of languages:

```
languages = ['ru', 'en', 'uk']
```

and i want to add prefix to field automatically. Something like this (NodeJS):

```
var langs = ['ru', 'en', 'uk']
var i18n = (obj) => {
  var result = {};
  _.mapKeys(obj, (value, key) => langs.forEach((lang) => {
    result[`${key}_${lang}`] = value;
  }));

  return result;
}

.. in model

_.merge(CityModel, i18n({
   title: {type: DataTypes.STRING(64)},
}));
```

It's possible in Phoenix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add fields to a schema from variables at compile time like this:

```
@columns [%{name: "title", type: :string}, %{name: "content", type: :string}]
@languages ~w(ru en uk)

schema "news" do
  for %{name: name, type: type} <- @columns, language <- @languages do
    field :"#{name}_#{language}", type
  end
end
```

This will generate the following fields/types:

```
:title_ru, :string
:title_en, :string
:title_uk, :string
:content_ru, :string
:content_en, :string
:content_uk, :string
```

If you don't have these fields in the database already, you'll have to do a similar loop in the migration as well.

Comment: @AlexMarchenko I just added a nested loop example as well, similar to your question. Hope that helps too!